Looking for a young-adult book about kids that get stuck in a cave
As near as I can remember, I read this book in 7th or 8th grade, so figure it would be written toward 10-15 year olds. I'm looking for a book where 2-4 (can't remember exactly) kids decide to explore an old cave/mine system. This isn't a fall-in-the-well rescue story. They get trapped and have to proceed forward to escape, but they were at least partially prepared because I remember them using the terms "belaying" and so on as they explore further. They overcome a number of obstacles and work their way through the cave to ultimately escape.
Any thoughts would be appreciated. My son is fascinated with caving and I thought it might be an interesting read for him.

What SF or fantasy elements does this story have?

That immediately reminds me of The Cave by Richard Church. But if that's right, there are no SF or F elements to it.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about science fiction or fantasy

This might be a good fit for Lit.SE

Not The Adventures of Tom Sawyer, I suppose? With Tom and Becky getting lost in the cave? :)

I guess my definition of "Fantasy" is a little to broad, sorry. When I grew up, that was the section of the library this book was in. But yes, I think The Cave (aka Five Boys in a Cave) seems to be it. Thanks.
